# How to configure Azure log analytics workspace to ship custom logs from VM

Tags: azure, oms

I wonder if Azure Log Analytics workspace is tied up to Resources Group? In other words, do you configure workspace per RG, or you can add more RGs to single workspace. I am having problems seeing logs shipped from another RG, initially workspace is configured for only one specific RG

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource Groups is only a logical container and has no such restrictions. Check this article to see if you have missed any configurations https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-sources-custom-logs

If you have done everything correct we might need some more insight into your setup to help you.